# Teradata: table is being loaded error (2652)

Tags: teradata

I have a table in Teradata which every operation i'm trying to do, i'm getting an error "Operation not allowed:  is being loaded".
How can i free that table?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There was a *Fastoad* or a *TPT Load* started on that table, but never finished. Do tables exist with a name like `thistable_ET` & `thistable_UV`?

The clean way would be restarting/finishing that load.

But as the table must have been empty before the load you might simply drop & recreate it (and don't forget those `_ET`/`_UV` tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see the _ET/_UV tables, the table may have also been mloaded, which can be cleared  by the "release mload ${table_name}" command. In this case you will be getting two errors in the log, one being 2574 preceding the 2652.

A more drastic method would be to try to drop the table, if other methods fail.